# Snap on choke on coax line leading from radio. Wrapped an LED around the choke and it lights with transmission, but only on certain bands? SWR?

Tags: coaxial-cable, swr-meter

Why does a LED wrapped around a snap-on Choke attached to radio antennae coax only light up when transmitting on certain bands? Is this an indication of high reflected power in the braid inducing enough current to light the LED, or the opposite?

Comment: Can you include a picture of how you placed the LED in your question? That might affect what sort of coupling is occurring.

Comment: Interesting. Add the picture to your question as @KevinReidAG6YO asked, and I'll upvote your question. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have privileges to upload photos yet. It is a 1" donut shaped choke snapped onto my antenna line. I used small (16g) insulated wire to wrap around the donut through the whole and attached led to both ends. It lights brightly on 7MHz and 14MHz, but none of the higher armature bands.  My output is 100Watts. EFHV with 49:1 Unun at base of antenna wire.

Comment: I will run SWR tests on my set up again. Oddly, according to my antennae analyzer, my SWR is <1.5 on the two bands that light the LED. I added a small resister to the led line to prevent burn out. The LED has 8 wraps through the core to make it mor likely to pick up current. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MikeWaters it's true! But you can just go to imgur.com/upload (if you're on a computer, didn't work on my phone) and upload there and then just add the link to the question. Same hoster, in the end.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. That's not a good idea. It may be the same operator, but the images are subject to different policies, and Imgur — like many other free image hosts before it — [has decided to start deleting "old" things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur#History), and might change their policy further in the future. By using the SE-specific version, you benefit from SE's interest in ensuring the images will continue to be available.

Comment: I was hoping someone with enough reputation would then convert the link to an embedded picture, elevating the image to a paid for one

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Sorry — I see too many people thinking they're the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

The snap on choke contains pieces of a ferrite core.  When you close the pieces, the core presents a high impedance to any current that is on the surface of the coax shield.

When the coax is operating as designed, currents in the center conductor and shield oppose each other and their magnetic fields cancel.  However, it is possible to have current in the shield that instead of opposing the center conductor current has a polarity common with the center conductor.   This is called "common mode current".   The whole point of the choke is to choke common mode current which is typically caused by field interaction between the antenna and the coax shield.

This common mode current causes multiple problems including lost power radiating from the antenna, high SWR (as the coax typically is not a tuned radiator), and RF radiation out the entire length of the coax, including the portion in the shack, which can then lead to RF burns.

When you wrap the LED around the choke, you are making a transformer with the core of the choke acting as the core of the transformer, the coax shield making one winding of the first coil, and the LED leads being one winding of the second coil.   Thus power is transferred to the LED.   If the LED lights, it indicates there is power in the core and that the choke is doing something.  It doesn't, however, indicate how effective the choke is.  (Note: you can burn out the LED if the power is too high.  If you wrap the leads around the core more than once without shorting the turns, you increase the voltage presented to the LED, which may make it brighter and also more likely to burn out.)

This can occur on only some bands either because the antenna interacts more strongly with the coax on those bands, or because the antenna has high SWR on those bands and the reflected power would prefer to be common mode current than radiate out the antenna.

The choke can block some of the common mode current, but if the power is high enough, the choke will saturate and not be able to block remaining current.  Adding more chokes can improve this.   However, high power in the chokes can also heat the chokes and eventually destroy them if they can't dissipate the heat fast enough.

You can also make an "air balun" which may add additional choking impedance.   This is done by coiling the coax into tightly bound loops, with at least 5 loops, more will have a higher choking inductance.  This has no core to saturate (the core is "air"), so it can't overheat, but it needs more coils since it doesn't have the core to increase the inductance.

Sometimes you can also reduce common mode current by balancing the geometry of the coax with the geometry of the antenna, making it as perpendicular as possible to try to minimize field interaction with the antenna.